# Making / Deploying War file from Eclipse web project

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, ant

I don't know if some one asked this but I have a problem that I am working on this tutorial [Hello World Example with annotation driven Spring 3 MVC in Eclipse](http://www.raistudies.com/spring/spring-mvc/hello-world-example-spring-mvc-eclipse-annotation/) .Now I am very embarrassed to say that how can I make war file to deploy on tomcat. Please guide me in this regard. Thank you

P.S: Just to inform you that I have Tomcat 6.0 and eclipse indigo 3.7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have many options depending on the environment you're using; the more simple ways can be:

- for testing purpose you can reference a Tomcat installation inside your Eclipse in the Severs tab of the J2EE perspective and add your Dynamic Web Project to it; then you can control (start/stop/debug) your server from Eclipse
- to build a war to deploy, you can right click the Dynamic Web Project and choose Export War File

Comment: @AndreaColleoi Thanks a lot. Now I can make a war file with your second method. Another question, how can I compile classes by using ant?

Comment: You have to write a build.xml file according to ANT manual (http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html). Eclipse will recognize this type of file and will let you run it as Ant Build Script right clicking on it.

Comment: Thanks, do I have to use/write build.xml even I am using Annotations (hibernate) or....I am really confused.

Comment: Annotations do some work for you, but don't help you in the build process. If you want to make your build process more accurate try to look at Maven instead of Ant. You'll have to write a pom.xml instead of a build.xml, but you will work at a higher level of abstraction (more understandable by the programmer).

Comment: Ok but How do I know which dependencies I have to add in my pom.xml?

Comment: If you are using Eclipse 3.7 (indigo) you can search for dependencies in the pom viewer. For example, if you are using hibernate you will search "hibernate" and will add a dependency; if hibernate has dependencies from other libraries (indirect dependencies) maven will resolve them automatically. Normally a project have only a few direct dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Apache Maven as it will help you much as you project will get bigger and your will have a lot of dependencies. You can try it as Eclipse plugin (m2eclipse) or use it from command line.